# Why can't I access column data by integer from executeQuery obj?

Tags: java, jdbc, netrexx

I'm a two day newbie in both NetRexx and Java.

I tried to modify the IBM red book examples to create a multi-threaded tcp server that executes SQL on a firebird database.

The first attempt is here http://www.compkarori.co.nz:8000/NetRexx/JDBC-bridge.nrx

When I try to loop thru the column data

```
loop col=1 to nbr_columns 
 say 'Column' col
 -- say rs.getString(col) -- gives error Message:  Column name 1 not found in result set.
 if buffer = '' then 
     buffer = rs.getString(column_name).trim()
 else
     buffer = buffer || '|' || rs.getString(column_name).trim()
end
```

I get an error as in the code comments if I use the loop counter as the index viz: rs.getString(col) and so I am resorting to using the columnname.  But if I do this:

```
say rs.getString(1)
```

it's fine.  Is this because col is a Rexx string and not a Java integer or something?

Also, I have to close the socket and thread after each query otherwise I don't get any response back.   Is this necessary or can I somehow leave the thread running to accept new queries?

( ps: can someone add a NetRexx tag?? )

Comment: Solved it.  Need to force the compiler to recognise the integer value

`say rs.getString(int col)`

Still wondering though about whether I can re-use the thread/socket.

Comment: The getString method is overloaded which is why I need to force the int value. And I figured out on how to reuse the thread and socket .. noting that only the Oracle and Firebird/Interbase JDBC connection objects appear to be thread safe.

Comment: I'd submit an answer to this and then check it off (after a couple of days).  Otherwise folks come thinking you are still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getString method is overloaded which is why I need to force the int value. And I figured out on how to reuse the thread and socket .. noting that only the Oracle and Firebird/Interbase JDBC connection objects appear to be thread safe